Why does the Sketamari seem to have much more HP than the Bestiary states?
The bestiary says that the Sketamari has 10,800 HP, but when fighting it with MissingN▯, I dealt 100+ HP damage numbers a second, and it took multiple minutes to die, instead of the less than 2 minutes it should've been, since 10,800 / 100 = 108, a.k.a a minute and 48 seconds, if I were really dealing at least 100 damage a second.
It couldn't have powered up since it was a -101% Curse run, making enemies spawn but not move, not even the Sketamari, so it had no chance to roll over any other enemies and power up.
Do enemies have a hidden Armor stat to reduce damage? Or something similar?

Not sure if this can actually happen but isn't there the possibility of enemies spawning in proximity of the boss and getting absorbed anyway making it heal. while It's noticable on the Sketamari size if it absorbs a lot just a few might not make an impc other than just healing it enough for the fight to drag out.

@trappski - I wish it was that easy. At -101% Curse, enemies don't spawn fast enough for that to make sense, and my 100 Damage / second is me extremely low-balling the damage numbers I was getting. I could've been getting 200 Damage / s or more. ... Also the ball's HP doesn't grow that fast from the possible enemies that spawn anyway, at the default size my ball was at: https://vampire-survivors.fandom.com/wiki/Sketamari#Absorption
